# Why is reduce index 1-based sometimes?

Tags: javascript

I've just come across an annoying bug (in my code) that was caused by the JavaScript `Array.reduce` method.

I've created a minimal reproduction of the issue below.

```js
const people = [{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'fred'}, {name: 'john'}]

people.reduce((acc, person, i) => {
  if (i === 0) throw Error('this error is never thrown')
  if (i === 1) console.log(acc === people[0])
  console.log(i, person.name)
  return acc
})

people.reduce((acc, person, i) => {
  if (i === 0) console.log(acc === null)
  console.log(i, person.name)
  return acc
}, null)
```

Why does the first piece of code above iterate twice only whilst the second use of reduce iterates three times (once for each array item) as expected?

Are there any docs documenting this behaviour or is this a bug in Chrome? If it's not a bug, why does this behaviour exist?

Comment: You're passing an initial value. If you don't, the first item becomes the initial value, therefore `person` starts from the second item.

Comment: Look at the documentation of *initialValue* at [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Look at what the _result_ of the reduction is (`{ name: 'bob' }` in the first case, vs. `null` in the second). If you don't pass a default, the first value in the array is used. _"Are there any docs..."_ - https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array.prototype.reduce?

Comment: **Read the docs**: *A value to which previousValue is initialized the first time the callback is called. If initialValue is specified, that also causes currentValue to be initialized to the first value in the array. If initialValue is **not specified**, previousValue is initialized to the first value in the array, and currentValue is initialized to the second value in the array.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: It's not a bug. It's documented behaviour. You're just using `reduce` improperly.

Comment: I thought as much thanks

Comment: It's also important to note that `reduce` has a return value. You're not doing that. You may as well just use a for loop.

Comment: yeah thanks Andy - I am aware of that but I appreciate you pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) has the second param (optional) as initial value of the aggregation. From the docs:

> If initialValue is not specified, previousValue is initialized to the first value in the array, and currentValue is initialized to the second value in the array.

In your code `bob` is skipped and so is its index. So this is the correct behaviour